# Unable to increase Java heap memory via IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory, ram, intellij-14

#### Problem:

I run a WSL AlmaLinux with 15_000M allocated RAM, and launch my Java application via IntelliJ, on a OpenJDK 64-Bit.

I need to increase the max heap memory available to my Java application, but it caps at 4_093M.

#### Attempts:

I have tried to increase the max and initial heap memory:

- By adding:

```
-Xms12288m
-Xmx12288m
```

1. To: `PATH_TO_INTELLIJ/232.8660.185.vmoptions`
2. And to: `PATH_TO_INTELLIJ/bin/idea64.vmoptions`

- By running:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms12288m -Xmx12288m"
```

- Trying both methods with lower heap memory sizes.

#### Results:

This did not increased the heap memory as confirmed:

- By the RES field in top:

```
  PID USER  PR  NI    VIRT     RES    SHR  S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5123  usr  20   0   9991.9m   3.5g  21896 S 672.7  22.9  74:06.11 java
```

- By JProfiler:

[Profile of a run launched via IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27U9C.png)

- By `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`:

```
4093M
```

If you have any idea (pun unintended), please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried to add "-Xms12288m -Xmx12288m" to the VM options field in Run/ Debug configuration?

Comment: Yes I have. It results to the same.

Comment: Could you please share execution command mentioned at the beginning of the output tool window?